# In Visual Studio with XML documentation: How to reference other param?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, xml-documentation

(In my case I am writing C# code in Visual Studio Community 2019 to use in Unity.)

I have not at all been able to find any way of doing this, unless I'd want to go through the trouble of learning how to write my own extensions to Visual Studio, so here I ask:

**Question:**
Is it possible to, when writing for example a `<param>`, to simply tell it to use another `<param>`?

**Example:**
For example, take the following code:

```cs
public class TextClass
{
    Vector3 pos;
    Vector3 rot;

    ///<summary> Moves the object. </summary>
    ///<param name="newPos"> The new position of the object. </param>
    public void Move(Vector3 newPos)
    {
        pos = newPos;
    }

    ///<summary> Moves the object. </summary>
    ///<param name="newPos"> The new position of the object. </param>
    ///<param name="newRot"> The new rotation of the object. </param>
    public void Move(Vector3 newPos, Vector3 newRot)
    {
        pos = newPos;
        rot = newRot;
    }
}
```

For the two `Move` functions, both have "Moves the object." as a summary and "The new position of the object." as a `param` for `newPos`. I would heavily prefer to be able to tell the first Move-function to just use the summary and `param` of the second `Move` function.

Comment: No, you cannot do that with the XML documentation block. If you absolutely must, consider using [T4 templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/writing-a-t4-text-template?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @GSerg, this sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is what [inheritdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc) can be used for. You can have your first Move function use that to inherit the documentation of the second Move function.